# Using the word pair for get on well together

Tags: word-usage, american-english

Situation: There is a person with whom I work as a freelancer and we <strike>both</strike> get on well together. How could I express this? Is saying "we make good pair" correct? Or "pair" is used for romantic relationships. Is there any other way to express this?

Comment: To *make a good **couple*** usually implies two people who are ***romantically attached***. The same with ***pair*** can be used with that sense, but ***pair*** can also be used of any two people who get on well together and/or ***perform*** well together (for an audience, to get a job done, or whatever).

Comment: *Pair* is countable, so it has to be "**a** good pair".

Answer (score 4):

[Pair](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pair) doesn't necessarily imply a romantic relationship between two people, but it is probably not the best term to use to describe a working relationship.

You could use the formal expression "work well together" or the informal expression "make a good team". Note that [team](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/team) has a specific meaning relating to a work environment, and it's OK to use this meaning for just two people.

This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work%20well%20together%2C%20make%20a%20good%20team&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwork%20well%20together%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20good%20team%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwork%20well%20together%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20good%20team%3B%2Cc0) shows that both expressions are quite widely used.